# access sql check if an index exists before creating

Tags: c#, ms-access, indexing

I'm creating an index on table in an access database, programmatically:

```
CREATE INDEX ind ON tableA (columnb);
```

Is there a way I can do a "if not exists" before trying to create the index?

Thanks!

Comment: From what language are you creating that index? VBA?

Comment: c#, I have an app that is importing data from access database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can be quite so neat with Access, but here are a few notes. I know nothing of C#, so the following is based only on some knowledge of Access.

```
string connectionString = 
      "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\docs\\some.mdb";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();

//Number of restriction columns: 5
//Restriction columns: TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, INDEX_NAME, TYPE, TABLE_NAME

string[] restrictions = new string[5];
restrictions[2] = "SomeKey";
restrictions[4] = "SomeTable";

System.Data.DataTable table = con.GetSchema("Indexes",restrictions);
```

References
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668764.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135852.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709712(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think there would be an elegant solution like I had hoped, but this works great, thank you!!

Comment: It may be possible to be neater with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbschemaguid.indexes.aspx